# How to configure Library Shares for additional TeamProject?

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, mtm, lab-management

i have an already existing TFS TeamProject with a connected SCVMM, all is working fine. Now i created an additional TeamProject. If I'm working with the old TeamProject in MTM, all works fine. If I change to the new TeamProject i havn't longer the possibilty to create a SCVMM Environment or open the Library Tab. The option to create SCVMM Environment is disabled and on Library tab i just get the error "there are currently no library shares configured for the following project: NewProject."
Do anybody have a clue where to configure a new TeamProject for Library Shares?

BR Mario

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether this team project is created under the same team project collection as other team projects. If you create the team project in a new team project collection, then go to TFS administrator console to check whether you have configured Library Shares for this team project collection:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. The new teamproject is created in the same collection like the old one.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side. You may try to verify the status of the library shares in the Lab Management Settings to see what result you will get.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the share has been added, e.g.:

```
TfsLabConfig.exe TPLibraryShare /list /Collection:<collection> /Teamproject:<teamproject>
```

If it is not there, add it to the team project like this:

```
TfsLabConfig.exe TPLibraryShare /add /Collection:<collection> /Teamproject:<teamproject> /TeamprojectcollectionLibraryShare:*
```